# Failed to load dynamic library 'libtensorflowlite_c.so': dlopen failed: library "libtensorflowlite_c.so" not found

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, face-detection

When I tried to call

```
 /// runs and transforms the data 
  this._interpreter.run(input, output);
```

> this._interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('mobilefacenet.tflite',
> options: interpreterOptions);

**Got this error**

> Failed to load dynamic library 'libtensorflowlite_c.so': dlopen failed: library "libtensorflowlite_c.so" not found

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users:

1. Copy all these lines on notepad:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal enableextensions

   cd %~dp0

   set TF_VERSION=2.5
   set URL=https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin/releases/download/
   set TAG=tf_%TF_VERSION%

   set ANDROID_DIR=android\app\src\main\jniLibs\
   set ANDROID_LIB=libtensorflowlite_c.so

   set ARM_DELEGATE=libtensorflowlite_c_arm_delegate.so
   set ARM_64_DELEGATE=libtensorflowlite_c_arm64_delegate.so
   set ARM=libtensorflowlite_c_arm.so
   set ARM_64=libtensorflowlite_c_arm64.so
   set X86=libtensorflowlite_c_x86_delegate.so
   set X86_64=libtensorflowlite_c_x86_64_delegate.so

   SET /A d = 0

   :GETOPT
   if /I "%1"=="-d" SET /A d = 1

   SETLOCAL
   if %d%==1 CALL :Download %ARM_DELEGATE% armeabi-v7a
   if %d%==1 CALL :Download %ARM_64_DELEGATE% arm64-v8a
   if %d%==0 CALL :Download %ARM% armeabi-v7a
   if %d%==0 CALL :Download %ARM_64% arm64-v8a
   CALL :Download %X86% x86
   CALL :Download %X86_64% x86_64
   EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

   :Download
   curl -L -o %~1 %URL%%TAG%/%~1
   mkdir %ANDROID_DIR%%~2\
   move /-Y %~1 %ANDROID_DIR%%~2\%ANDROID_LIB%
   EXIT /B 0
   ```
2. Save the file as `install.bat` and put the file in root directory of your    project.
3. Open in explorer and open a command window there.
4. Type `install.bat` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Use `install.bat -d` (Windows) instead if you wish to use `GpuDelegateV2` and `NnApiDelegate`.

---

For Linux/Mac users:

1. Copy all these lines on notepad

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"

   # Available versions
   # 2.5, 2.4.1

   TF_VERSION=2.5
   URL="https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin/releases/download/"
   TAG="tf_$TF_VERSION"

   ANDROID_DIR="android/app/src/main/jniLibs/"
   ANDROID_LIB="libtensorflowlite_c.so"

   ARM_DELEGATE="libtensorflowlite_c_arm_delegate.so"
   ARM_64_DELEGATE="libtensorflowlite_c_arm64_delegate.so"
   ARM="libtensorflowlite_c_arm.so"
   ARM_64="libtensorflowlite_c_arm64.so"
   X86="libtensorflowlite_c_x86_delegate.so"
   X86_64="libtensorflowlite_c_x86_64_delegate.so"

   delegate=0

   while getopts "d" OPTION
   do
        case $OPTION in
            d)  delegate=1;;
       esac
   done


   download () {
       wget "${URL}${TAG}/$1" -O "$1"
       mkdir -p "${ANDROID_DIR}$2/"
       mv $1 "${ANDROID_DIR}$2/${ANDROID_LIB}"
   }

   if [ ${delegate} -eq 1 ]
   then

   download ${ARM_DELEGATE} "armeabi-v7a"
   download ${ARM_64_DELEGATE} "arm64-v8a"

   else

   download ${ARM} "armeabi-v7a"
   download ${ARM_64} "arm64-v8a"

   fi

   download ${X86} "x86"
   download ${X86_64} "x86_64"
   ```
2. Save the file as install.sh name and put the file in root directory of your    project.
3. Open a command window there.
4. Type `sh install.sh` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Use `sh install.sh -d` instead if you wish to use `GpuDelegateV2` and `NnApiDelegate`.

Comment: Adding some comments and explaining your answer will be more useful.

Comment: solved the problem. thank for sharing.

Comment: Solved my problem, Yet I'm not sure what just happened. Hope you can explain whats going on.

Comment: So I wasn't able to run this script earlier so I changed the `wget` to `curl` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: if anyone is getting an error which says "install.bat command not found" you should try typing .\install.bat and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

After using the `install.sh` file, that error showed (only on Android, iOS worked fine). But I had changed the `wget` to `curl` in the install file and it had downloaded a redirect html page.

The replacement that worked for me was:

```sh
# wget "${URL}${TAG}/$1" -O "$1" # Replaced with the below line          
curl -L "${URL}${TAG}/$1" -o "$1"
```

Try to confirm that the files you have downloaded are the correct files. You can inspect these files in `<projectdirectory>/android/app/src/main/jniLibs`. They should be binary files that begin with `^?ELF`, not html files like what I had.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file in the root directory in the app found in
**tflite_flutter** package. [tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter). You can also find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_SNZSQw0YtbtlP7fBwh8kqB5rZWxx1q3/view?usp=sharing).
just download the file and place it into the root directory in your app and double click to install the needed information. (For Windows)

Answer (score 0):

For Android Platform:

Place the script `install.sh` (Linux/Mac) or `install.bat` (Windows) at the root of your project.

Execute this .sh:

[install.sh](https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin/blob/master/install.sh) <= (Linux/Mac)

[install.bat](https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin/blob/master/install.bat) <= (Windows)

files at the root of your project to automatically download and place the binaries in appropriate folders.

Note: The binaries installed will not include support for GpuDelegateV2 and NnApiDelegate however `InterpreterOptions().useNnApiForAndroid` can still be used.

**How to use .sh**

*Linux/Mac*

```
install.sh -d
```

*Windows*

```
install.bat -d
```

instead if you wish to use these GpuDelegateV2 and NnApiDelegate.

Read More: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter